# Why does this audio file autoplay?

Tags: html, audio, autostart, autoplay

This keeps autoplaying even when I set it to false 3 times. I don't know what to do it's getting on my nerves. Any ideas?

```
<object>
<param name="src" value="http://linkimprov.com/buu.mp3">
<param name="autoplay" value="false">
<param name="autostart" value="false">
<param name="controller" value="true">
<embed src="http://linkimprov.com/buu.mp3" controller="true" autoplay="false" autostart="False" type="audio/mp3" />
</object>
```

You can see how it autostarts in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lisandro/wCJzm/3/

I just started web design and audio is making me want to cut my pc in pieces. Any ideas of why it autoplays??

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

better to use this tag

```
<audio controls="controls">
<source src="http://linkimprov.com/buu.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
</audio>
```

it's working for me!!

Comment: in fact simple missing out loop and autoplay attribute in <audio> does the trick of not playing. One can still use javascript to call play();

Answer (score -2):

works great for IE and *mp3 files but Firefox doesn't support *.mp3 files.  It supports *.ogg audio files.  Having to have two versions of each of your audio files isn't really a solution.  Also, try to find a simple command line utility to create your *.ogg files... good luck.

Comment: This is incorrect. Firefox supports type="audio/mp3" for <audio> and <source> tags